# Find the field of fractions and the integral closure of a subring of $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $R$ be a subring of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ consisting of polynomials such that the coefficients of $x$ and $x^2$ are zero.

1. Find the field of fractions of $R$.
2. Find the integral closure of $R$ in it's field of fractions.
3. Show that $R$ cannot be generated as a ring by 1 and a polynomial $f(x) \in R$.

---

I feel like the answers I have are correct, but at the same time I feel like I'm missing something here. Do these solutions look right?

1. Let $\mathbb{K}$ be the field of fractions, then certainly $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{K}$ because of $\mathbb{Z}$. Also $\frac{1}{x^3} \in \mathbb{K}$ so $\frac{1}{x^3} \cdot x^5 = x^2 \in \mathbb{K}$, likewise $\frac{1}{x^4} \cdot x^5 = x \in \mathbb{K}$. Thus $\mathbb{K}$ must be $\mathbb{Q}(x)$.
2. $R$ is a UFD because $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD, thus $R$ is integrally closed. i.e., it's integral closure is itself.
3. Suppose it were, then consider the homomorphism, $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[t] \to R $, such that $t \mapsto f(x) $. Then $\phi$ is injective, implying $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$, contradiction.

Comment: 3. I think you want to say that $R\simeq\mathbb Z[t]$.

Comment: Just wondering, why not just pick $\frac{x^5}{x^4} = x$? Why do you have to do $\frac{1}{x^3} \in K and \frac{1}{x^3} x^5 = x^2 \in K$? I mean isn't it true that as long as x is in it that k is q[x]?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing your argument for $2$ is that you can use factorization in $\mathbf{Z}[x]$ to factor in $R$.

The problem is that when you use factorization in $\mathbf{Z}[x]$, the factors will may not be in $R$! In particular, consider the problem of factoring of $x^8$.

Comment: In $R$ wouldn't $x^8 = x^3 \cdot x^5$. Here $x^3$ and $x^5$ would be considered as irreducible elements in $R$ since they can't be factored into a product of elements in $R$?

Comment: @algor: Don't overlook $(x^4)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

2. Since $x$ is integral over $R$ the extension $R\subset\mathbb Z[x]$ is integral. Moreover, $\mathbb Z[x]$ is integrally closed, so the integral closure of $R$ (in its field of fractions) is $\mathbb Z[x]$.
3. Actually $R=\mathbb Z[x^3,x^4,x^5]$. The question ask to prove that $R$ can't be generated as a $\mathbb Z$-algebra by a single element. If $R=\mathbb Z[f]$ with $f\in R$, then $R$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring over $\mathbb Z$, so $R$ is integrally closed, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

(1) seems ok.

For (2), notice that $x$ is a root of the monic polynomial $g(t)=t^3-x^3$ which is defined over $R$, so that $R$ is not integrally closed.

For (3), even if you have an isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[t]\to R$, it doesn't mean that $R$ as a subring of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ must be the whole ring. For example, $\mathbb{Z}[x^2]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. (hint: if $t\mapsto f(t)$ then $g(t)\mapsto g(f(t))$. Can such a homomorphism be onto?)

Comment: For (3), suppose for every $a(x) \in R$, $a(x) = g(f(x))$ for some $g(t) \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$, then if $a(x)$ is not a constant, then $a(x)$ is of degree at most 3, so $f(x) = f_3x^3 +f_0$. But $x^5 \in R$ but there doesn't exist $g(t)$ such that $g(f_3x^3 + f_0) = x^5$ because $g(f_3x^3 + f_0)$ will have exponents that are multiples of 3. So it's not onto.

Comment: But I don't see how it not being onto gives me a contradiction especially given your example that $\mathbb{Z}[x^2] \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: @algor207 If you assume that R can be generated by 1 and f, then the map you defined must be onto. The ring $\mathbb{Z}[x^2]$ on the other hand is generated by 1 and a single polynomial $x^2$.

Comment: Forgive my endless questions, but I don't see how the map is onto. Given my argument above, how can one find a $g(t)$ such that $g(f(x)) = x^5$ since $f(x)$ would have to be of degree 3. I guess I'm making an obvious mistake, but for some reason I can't see it.

Comment: @algor207 I might have been a little bit ambiguous. I meant that if you assume that the ring R is generated by 1 and f, then the map $\phi$ that you defined in your original question is onto, but as you said, using degree considerations, there cannot be such a map.